# Php artisan keep giving [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException] Parse Error

Tags: php, symfony, laravel-5, laravel-artisan

Hello guys i'm new with laravel and need help there.
I was developing with laravel framework (version 5.4) on windows and i attempt to copy my project to my macbook.

Now wherenever i run the `php artisan migrate` it always say `[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]  Parse Error`, only that feedback.

I got so confuse and no idea what to do.

Can someone tell me how to fix this?

Comment: Check your php version and verify it confirms the requirements of the framework.

Comment: alright now i already verified the php version. And now i got a different message from my artisan migrate; it says   Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}'

Comment: Ah i found my fault with the migration file that i make. Thanks napuzba this is really helpful